# How to work with "Drupal Module" project in PhpStorm

Tags: drupal-7, phpstorm

As stated here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/preparing-for-drupal-development-in-phpstorm.html ("Creating a PhpStorm project with a Drupal module" part) - one of project types PhpStorm can create is "Drupal Module". Which will create module bare bones (`.module` and `.info` files) and allow me to set path to Drupal installation and PHP executable.

My question is: how can I see the results of module I'm developing? Let's say my module only displays message using `drupal_set_message()` function. How can I see the message?

I could copy the module into Drupal /sites/all/modules - but then what would be the purpose of creating "Drupal Module" project? It seems to me that the only thing the "Drupal Module" project does is creating module bare bones and nothing else. Em I missing something here? Why would I want to use "Drupal Module" project - are there any adventages?

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Drupal+Development+using+PhpStorm

Comment: @LazyOne - thanks, but I already know that page. It explains how to configure PhpStorm, but it doesn't explain how to use "Drupal Module" project. I mean - I can build the module, but I can't see the results as Drupal doesn't see the module

Comment: How do you add this to Drupal? Any errors there?